# Airplay: stream video and audio components to different Airplay target devices

Tags: appletv, airplay

I'm thinking about getting a [Libratone](http://www.libratone.com) sound system that plays music via Airplay. I would have an Apple TV connected to an LCD projector.

My question is whether I would be able to wirelessly stream a movie from my iPad with this setup, such that audio goes to the Libratone and video goes to the Apple TV...

I couldn't find any information on this kind of setup.

Comment: I think your only option would be wiring the audio output from the projector to your sound system.

Answer (score 1):

It just isn't feasible at this time. Video and audio need to stay perfectly in sync for your brain to not notice, and splitting up the streams of data to two different destinations creates a time lag that, at this time, is impossible to sync up.  The reason why it works at all going to one device is that the destination spools up both streams and starts them both at the same time.

Comment: The reason why it's not possible right now is nobody has done it yet, not that the underlying idea is impossible. We split audio and video streams all day long (using wires) in modern home theater systems. There is no logical reason why it couldn't be made to work wirelessly. It would be very difficult to keep everything in sync, but there are a lot of smart developers who thrive on solving those types of problems.